# React Component check is variable is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a react component where I also have a variable in the class/component/

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';

export class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.myvar = 'some text';
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.myvar}</div>
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

How would I check if "myvar" is empty and if it is so something with the component above?

Comment: Define "empty" in this case?

Comment: Empty ... No text at all

Comment: why are you not using React states?

Comment: So an empty string? Will `this.myvar` ever have a value that is not a string?

Comment: Also, React doesn't provide any tools to check the "emptyness" of a variable/value. It's just JavaScript, so use whatever you normally use.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{!!(this.myvar)?this.myvar:"whatever you want"}</div>//
      </div>

    );
  }
```

> **!!**: check for undefined, null, and empty value

Comment: I was looking for a method which could be fired instead on inline?

Comment: @JakeBrown777 : {!!(this.myvar)?this.myvar:func()}.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Don't understand the down votes

Comment: @JakeBrown777. Great.

Comment: FWIW, this will also consider `0` and `false` as "emtpy".

Answer (score 7):

The provided solution runs afoul of eslint's [no-extra-boolean-casts](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-extra-boolean-cast) rule.

An alternate method that makes eslint happy would look like this:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{!this.myvar ? "whatever you want" : this.myvar}</div>//
      </div>

    );
  }
```